# Problem of incorrect output for dictionary returned from file

Tags: python, python-3.x

File contains student ID and ID of the solved problem. 
Example:

```
1,2
1,4
1,3
2,1
2,2
2,3
2,4
```

The task is to write a function which will take a filename as an argument and return a dictionary with a student ID and amount of solved tasks. 
Example output:

```
{1:3, 2:4}
```

My code which doesn't support the correct output. Please, help me find a mistake and a solution.

```
import collections
def solved_tasks(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            key,value = line.strip().split(',')
            dictionary = {key: collections.Counter(str(value))}
    return dictionary
```

Comment: Can there be duplicate lines, e.g. twice `2,1`?

Comment: What is the error? Using a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) might help

Comment: yes, it is possible

Comment: there is no error, it is just do not iterable, stops in the beginning of cycle

Comment: You are creating a *new* dictionary with a *new* counter every time you encounter a key.

Comment: how can i solve the problem? by putting it in one variable?

Comment: How should the dictionary look like with your input? You have `1,2; 1,4; 1,3` in the file. Would this look like `{1:[2,3,4]}` in your dictionary?

Comment: And, just to be clear, if there are duplicate entries, should those be counted as one or two visited courses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only care about the sum, not the individual exercises, you can use a `Counter` on the first column:

```
def solved_tasks(filename):
    with open(filename) as in_stream:
        counts = collections.Counter(
            line.partition(',')[0]         # first column ...
            for line in in_stream if line  # ... of every non-empty row
        )
    return {int(key): value for key, value in counts.items()}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can count how often a key appears

```
marks = """1,2
            "1,4
            "1,3
            "2,1
            "2,2
            "2,3
            "2,4
            "2,4"""
dict = {}
for line in marks.split("\n"):
    key,value = line.strip().split(",")
    dict[key] = dict.get(key,[]) + [value]


for key  in dict:
    dict[key] = len(set(dict[key])) # eliminate duplicates
```

the `dict.get(key,[])` method returns an empty list if the key doesn't exist in the dict as a default parameter.

@Edit: You said there may contain duplicates. This method would eliminate all duplicates.

@Edit: Added multilines with """

Comment: You can create a multiline string using ``"""``. Also, when reading from a file Python by default uses universal newlines, meaning ``"\r\n"`` is automatically converted to ``"\n"``.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to save the repeated instances of student id, you can use a `defaultdict` and save the problems solved by each student as a list in your dictionary:

```
import collections

dictionary = collections.defaultdict(list)

def solved_tasks(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            key,value = line.strip().split(',')
            dictionary[key].append(value)
    return dictionary
```

Output:

`defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'1': ['2', '4', '3'], '2': ['1', '2', '3', '4']})`

If you want the sum:

```
def solved_tasks(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            key,value = line.strip().split(',')
            dictionary[key] += 1
    return dictionary
```

Output:

`defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'1': 3, '2': 4})`

Comment: Why the global ``dictionary`` instead of creating in the function?

Answer (score -2):

```
def solved_tasks(filename):
    res = {}
    values=""
    with open(filename, "r") as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
           values += line.strip()[0] #take only the first value and concatinate with the values string

    value = values[0] #take the first value
    res[int(value)] = values.count(value) #put it in the dict
    for i in values: #loop the values
        if i != value: # if the value is not the first value, then the value is the new found value
            value = i
            res[int(value)] = values.count(value) #add the new value to the dict
    return res
```